# Running jesque workers as a process

Tags: spring, jvm, jobs, jesque

I have an spring application which is serving APIs. Now want to develop a background job using the same spring context and I was planning to use [jesque](https://github.com/gresrun/jesque) for that. I followed the jesque documentation for initializing the workers and enqueuing the jobs and its working fine.

- The concern I have here is workers run as a thread in the same JVM as my main application whereas I wanted a worker to be a process in itself just like we have in [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) for rails so that I can monitor and control it easily.
- The other advantage will be that, whenever an application deploy/restart is in progress(ie. killing a JVM process and starting it again) the workers will not be killed at the same time and will keep processing the jobs. I should be able to restart them gracefully later on.

How can we start the jesque workers as a process?

Comment: I also need to run jesque threads as seperate process . Have you find any way with which we can achieve this ?